# Belkin Bluetooth and Wireless USB Adapter

Tags: usb, printing, bluetooth

I have a Windows XP (SP3) machine with a Belkin F8T012 USB adapter plugged into it.  I also have a Belkin F8T031 Wireless USB Printer Adapter with an HP 5900 DeskJet plugged into it.  Everytime I try to print I get asked to enter the pairing code.  I read in the documentation for the F8T012 that some devices use 0000 or 1234 as a default.  Neither of these work.

I used these same Belkin devices and printer on a Windows 2000 and a Windows Vista setup and had no problems; printing worked perfectly.  I cannot get it to work on my Windows XP machine.

I have uninstalled and re-installed the Bluetooth software (both ver 4.0.1.2401 and 5.1.0.1700)

What else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following website has a listing of working and NON working Bluetooth devices.

Your device Belkin F8T012 USB is listed on the page with a link next to it saying it needs an update to work under XP. Search for it on the page.

I would go down this path to see if you can get it working. Next to it is a link to the Broadcom website to get the update for your device.

http://wiibrew.org/wiki/List_of_Working_Bluetooth_Devices#Working_Bluetooth_Devices_on_XP.2FLinux.2C_but_are_not_compatible_with_Vista

Comment: Awesome!  This is the first time I've printed via this computer since I swapped it from Vista to XP over a year ago!  BTW, I did get an error during the install that said the file BTW.msi was missing; I just hit OK and everything else worked. All is good.

Answer (score 0):

I'm placing this info here for future googlers. It comes from [a reviewer](http://www.amazon.com/review/RNDN9RBYIH6B2/ref=cm_cr_pr_viewpnt#RNDN9RBYIH6B2) at Amazon.com. Note the critical info about the passkey:

> This dongle works great, using only my
>   Palm with Bluefish RX software. No
>   complaints except one, and hopefully
>   this will help some buyers.
>
> To initially set up your handheld
>   device, when it asks for a passkey,
>   which is a kind of password,
>
> THE PASSKEY IS "belkin" (all lower
>   case).